# linked List in a struct

Tags: c, pointers, struct, linked-list

I'm having a problem with changing the address of a pointer in a struct.
The funcion receives a service type (a pointer to a struct) and an ID. The service contains a linked list of type apartments (pointer to an apartment struct), and I want to find the apartment with the given ID and remove it from the list. The problem is- when I go back to the original function, service->listedApartment still points the same way as before..

```
ApartmentServiceResult serviceDeleteById(ApartmentService service, int id) {
    Node previous = NULL;
    Node after = NULL;
    Node current = service->listedApartments;
    while (current != NULL) {
        after = current->next;
        if (current->id == id) {
            apartmentDestroy(current->apartment); //deletes the apartment
            free(current);
            if (previous == NULL) {
                service->listedApartments = after;
            } else {
                previous->next = after;
                service->listedApartments=previous;
            }
            return APARTMENT_SERVICE_SUCCESS;
        }
        previous = current;
        current = current->next;
    }
    return APARTMENT_SERVICE_NO_FIT;
}
```

Comment: @wildplasser - If you notice there is a return at the end of that if statement. Therefore that should not be the problem

Comment: Oops, I got confused by the excesive amount of `{}`, I guess. And the bulkload of helper variables, and the trailing `p = p.next;' .

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that you're passing a reference?

With this line you're passing your struct by value, that means the function will make a copy of the passed paramether and modify it, without changing the value outside.

```
ApartmentServiceResult serviceDeleteById(ApartmentService service, int id) {
```

To pass by reference you have to explicitly put the * and treat the reference accordingly:

```
ApartmentServiceResult serviceDeleteById(ApartmentService * service, int id) {
```

Unless you did some magic with the typedef, I guess it might have been the issue.

Comment: The thing is that service is already a pointer to a struct.. @Denilson Mello

Comment: Yea, let us see the other functions too

Answer (score 1):

Removing the (not shown in the OQ) typedefs, and using just `struct xx*` and `struct yy*`, the fragment can be reduced to:

```
ApartmentServiceResult serviceDeleteById(struct xx *service, int id) {
struct yy **pp, *p;

for (pp= &service->listedApartments; (p = *pp); pp = &p->next) {
    if (p->id != id) continue;
    apartmentDestroy(p->apartment);
    *pp = p->next; /* steal the pointer */
    free(p);
    return APARTMENT_SERVICE_SUCCESS;
    }
return APARTMENT_SERVICE_NO_FIT;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In link list the very first thing to remember is that each time you call a function must be call by ref because you want that manipulation in your link list and your function `serviceDeleteById` is receiving its arguments by value. So modify it and try to run the code.

```
void del(int d)
{
    struct node *temp,*ptr;
    temp=start;
    while(temp!=NULL)
    {
        if(temp->link->info==d)
        {
            ptr=temp->link;
            temp->link=ptr->link;
            free(ptr);
        }
        temp=temp->link;
    }
}
```

This code sample will help you with code. You can check [more here](http://ccodinggeek.blogspot.in/search/label/link%20list).